# How to add an icon in drawable.xml after inserting vector asset?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, drawable

I wanted some additional icons for my android studio project so I added in drawable folder through New > Vector Asset. The problem here is my drawable.xml file doesn't recognize my `ic_menu_logout` file. The code:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item name="ic_menu_camera" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera</item>
    <item name="ic_menu_gallery" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery</item>
    <item name="ic_menu_slideshow" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow</item>
    <item name="ic_menu_manage" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage</item>
    <item name="ic_menu_share" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_share</item>
    <item name="ic_menu_send" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_send</item>
    <item name="ic_menu_logout" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_logout</item>
</resources>
```

The last line containing `ic_menu_logout` displays an error. Maybe I missed something or did something wrong. Help me out here. Thanks.

**NOTE:**

The `ic_menu_logout` is an `.xml` file itself:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M10.09,15.59L11.5,17l5,-5 -5,-5 -1.41,1.41L12.67,11H3v2h9.67l-2.58,2.59zM19,3H5c-1.11,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v4h2V5h14v14H5v-4H3v4c0,1.1 0.89,2 2,2h14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2V5c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2z"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: i usually just change the extension to png and drag, drop them into the drawable folder and they work fine.

Comment: @ivan I edited my post, check it out. What if the file is an xml?

Comment: then, whats the error that you're getting?

Comment: @ivan `Cannot resolve symbol @android:drawable/ic_menu_logout`

Comment: is it really in your drawable folder? i cant see why it isnt working, it works fine with me.

Answer (score 5):

Replace **@android:drawable/ic_menu_logout** by only **@drawable/ic_menu_logout**

Answer (score 3):

> Replace @android:drawable/ic_menu_logout by only @drawable/ic_menu_logout

This solved my issue, thank you!

EDIT:
I ran into this issue, because I started off using a Navigation Drawer Activity. This includes some drawables like ic_menu_gallery in the res/drawable-v21 folder. However, it also includes a values/drawables.xml which includes aliases for all the drawables! These are specified as

```
 <item name="ic_menu_camera" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera</item>
```

which means that the android system drawables are always used and the drawables in the res/drawable-v21 folder are ignored. You can validate this by changing the color of the drawables in res/drawables-v21 folder.

My solution was to copy all the drawables from the drawables-v21 to the drawables folder and delete the drawables-v21 folder. I also deleted the values/drawable.xml file, as it completely useless and confuses people (me at least. ;))

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//stackoverflow.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Stack Overflow way of saying thank you.

Comment: I wanted to comment on his answer, but couldn't due to having not enough priviledges. I've spent some time here and I don't understand why you need 50 creds to comment on other peoples answers. Anyway - will modify my answer to be more helpful.